# MySQL - Fuzzy Match Text on Each Side of Newlines

Tags: mysql, mariadb, syntax

I am working on an issue where I need to check a street field or exact matches at a minimum but also, if at all possible, fuzzy matches. For example, if I have address `1234 Some Road`, it should at least direct match to `1234 Some Road` on the other side of the newline. I would also like to match `999 Somewhere Lane` and `999 Somewhere Ln`. Obviously, addresses won't have identical lengths so it has have some flexibility and there shouldn't be any more than two rows since the website this is on caps it at Address 1 and 2.

`select entity_id, parent_id, customer_address_id, quote_address_id, concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as 'name', street, city, region, postcode from sales_order_address where (street regexp "\n" or street regexp "\r" or street regexp "\r\n");`

This query found all rows with any type of newline but as stated above, I need to match the newlines as though they're unique 'rows'.

This comment - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50490998/18582667 - seems to imply this kind of matching is possible, but I haven't found a definitive answer to that anywhere.

Even if I can't fuzzy match, a direct match will be fine and will help me locate street fields with an issue. I'm also fine with a roundabout way of matching so it doesn't need to be super concise.

What are my options, if any?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: None of those really worked for my specific situation... or I'm not sure how to apply split strings fully.

Comment: The link I posted was intended to give you an idea how to improve your question, not to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this one on my own after thinking a little harder about it.

```sql
select entity_id, parent_id, customer_address_id, 
 quote_address_id, concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as 'name', 
 street, city, region, postcode, 
 substring_index(street, '\n', 1),
 substring_index(street, '\n', -1)
from sales_order_address 
where (street regexp "\n" or street regexp "\r" or street regexp "\r\n") AND
substring_index(street, '\n', 1) = substring_index(street, '\n', -1);
```

This did exactly what I needed for a direct match.

I used a simple tutorial to get me to the answer: https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-split-a-string-in-mysql/.

Comment: That can be significantly simplified by trimming off "whitespace" (which includes `\r` and `\n`) before inserting the data and before building the `WHERE`.

Comment: I'm limited in how the data is inserted so I had to do it this way to get what I needed.